# angular material paginator can't set the page size

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using an angular material paginator.

```html
<div style="  display:block;">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of dataDisplayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
       <mat-header-cell class="table-header header-p" *matHeaderCellDef>
         <b>{{ col }}</b> 
       </mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell class="table-content context-position" *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element[col] }}
       </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>

     <mat-header-row class="table-header header-p-row" *matHeaderRowDef="dataDisplayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
     <mat-row matRipple 
       [ngClass]="((row['num']%2) == 1) ? 'row-single' : 'row-double'" 
       *matRowDef="let row; columns: dataDisplayedColumns;">
     </mat-row> 
 </mat-table>

</div>
<mat-paginator #paginator class="paginator" 
  [pageSize]="10" 
  [hidePageSize]="true" 
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" 
  showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
```

The code is shown as followed.

```js
dataDisplayedColumns: string[] = [];
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
page = 1;
pageSize = 10;

var self = this;
this.dataSourceService.getConnectionData(connection)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
    .subscribe( (res: any) =>{
  if(res.data.length > 0) {
    console.log(Object.keys(res.data[0]));
    self.dataDisplayedColumns = Object.keys(res.data[0]);
    self.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);
    self.paginator.length = res.count;
    self.paginator.pageSize = 10;
    console.log(self.dataSource.data);
  }
},err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The problem is no matter how I am setting the paginator 's pageSize value in

```html
<mat-paginator #paginator class="paginator"  [pageSize]="10" [hidePageSize]="true" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

or using the code to set pageSize as 10

```js
self.paginator.pageSize = 10;
```

The table is still showing all the data on the page while the paginator 's pageSize is set as 10.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    dataDisplayedColumns: string[] = [];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
    page = 1;          //i think this
    pageSize = 10;     //and this are not used anywhere

    var self = this;
    this.dataSourceService.getConnectionData(connection)
                     .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
                     .subscribe( (res: any) =>{
    if(res.data.length>0){
      console.log(Object.keys(res.data[0]));
      self.dataDisplayedColumns = Object.keys(res.data[0]);
      self.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);
      self.paginator.length = res.count;
      self.paginator.pageSize = 10;
      self.dataSource.paginator = self.paginator;  //assigning paginator to dataSource
      console.log(self.dataSource.data);
       }
    },err => {
     console.log(err);
    });
```

you've to assign paginator to dataSource

try adding
`self.dataSource.paginator = self.paginator;`
to your code

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer was not working for me on a more recent angular version (13+)

This helped it to work

```
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let emp; let i =index"   [formGroupName]="i+paginator.pageSize*paginator.pageIndex">
      
  
    <input matInput  formControlName="{{column}}" value= {{emp[column]}} />
    
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```